# NavigationView icon colors

Tags: android, navigationview

I am using NavigationView in my application. XML menu contains 4 groups of items with icons and I want to apply app:itemIconTint only for 3 groups (gray icons). Last group of items should remain with original icons (no tint used). Is it possible?

I tried `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)`, but it changes all items.

Here is my NavigationView:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/White"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/_navigation_view_icon"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/_navigation_view_text"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/_navigation_view_background"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>
```